# Custom Model In Stanford NLP (CoreNLP) For Persian

Tags: python, java, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford NLP to extract data from text , knowing some code and work with this excellent library but some how , need to create my project in java that I know better than python , so found this code for use custom model :

```
import stanfordnlp

config = {
    'processors': 'tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse', # Comma-separated list of processors to use
    'lang': 'fa', # Language code for the language to build the Pipeline in
    'tokenize_model_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji_tokenizer.pt', # Processor-specific arguments are set with keys "{processor_name}_{argument_name}"
    'mwt_model_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji_mwt_expander.pt',
    'pos_model_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji_tagger.pt',
    'pos_pretrain_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji.pretrain.pt',
    'lemma_model_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji_lemmatizer.pt',
    'depparse_model_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji_parser.pt',
    'depparse_pretrain_path': './PersianPT/fa_seraji_models/fa_seraji.pretrain.pt'
}
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config) # Initialize the pipeline using a configuration dict
doc = nlp("من عاشقت هستم") # Run the pipeline on input text

with open('./Desktop/NLP/out.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for sen in doc.sentences[0]._tokens :
        f.write(sen.words[0].text + '---Upos : ' +sen.words[0].upos + '---Xpos : ' +sen.words[0].xpos + '\n')
doc.sentences[0].print_tokens()
```

which work fine in python but when using java to Implement the code , don't know why the output not the same!

Java Code :

```
public class TextAnalyzer {
    public static String text = """
            در ابتدا، زندگی‌نامه‌ها به عنوان یک بخش از تاریخ با تمرکز بر یک فرد خاص، با اهمیت تاریخی در نظر گرفته شد. انواع مستقل زندگی‌نامه‌نویسی با تمایز از تاریخ عمومی از قرن ۱۸ ام شروع شده و فرم‌های معاصر آن به قرن بیستم می‌رسد.
            """;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set up pipeline properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // set the list of annotators to run
        //props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
        //props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
        //props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
        //props.setProperty("processors", "tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse");
        
        //props.setProperty("processors", "tokenize, mwt, lemma, pos, depparse");
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse");
        
        //props.setProperty("lang", "fa");
        //props.setProperty("use_gpu", "true");
        props.setProperty("tokenize_model_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji_tokenizer.pt");
        props.setProperty("mwt_model_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji_mwt_expander.pt");
        props.setProperty("pos_model_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji_tagger.pt");
        props.setProperty("pos_pretrain_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji.pretrain.pt");
        props.setProperty("lemma_model_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji_lemmatizer.pt");
        props.setProperty("depparse_model_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji_parser.pt");
        props.setProperty("depparse_pretrain_path", BasicLocation.getBaseFileDirForNLPPersian() + File.separatorChar + "Seraji" + File.separatorChar +"fa_seraji.pretrain.pt");
        
        
        // build pipeline
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        // create a document object
       // CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
        
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        
        // annnotate the document
        //pipeline.annotate(document);
        // examples

        // 10th token of the document
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
          // Get the parse tree for each sentence
          Tree parseTree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
          // Do something interesting with the parse tree!
          System.out.println(parseTree);
        }
       




      }

    }
```

I think It's maybe about processors or arg (.model_path) that not exist in java library so if some one know about it , Please share
Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error in java or are you getting different results?  Either way it would be helpful to share your error or your results in the question.

Comment: @RodP I haven't got error the output show different result that not the same as the python shows , and the java result It's not right!

Comment: @RodP output in java : (ROOT (NP (NML (NNP در) (NNP ابتدا) (NNP ،) (NNP زندگینامهها) (NNP به)) (NNP عنوان) (NML (NNP یک) (NNP بخش) (NNP از) (NNP تاریخ) (NNP با)) (NNP تمرکز) (NML (NNP بر) (NNP یک) (NNP فرد) (NNP خاص) (NNP ،) (NNP با)) (NNP اهمیت) (NNP تاریخی) (NML (NNP در) (NNP نظر)) (NNP گرفته) (NNP شد) (. .)))
(ROOT (S (NP (CD انواع) (CD مستقل) (CD زندگینامهنویسی) (CD با) (CD تمایز) (CD از) (CD تاریخ) (CD عمومی) (CD از) (CD قرن) (CD ۱۸) (CD ام) (CD شروع) (CD شده) (CD و) (CD فرمهای) (CD معاصر)) (VP (VBZ آن) (NP (NML (NNP به) (NNP قرن)) (NNP بیستم) (NNP میرسد))) (. .)))

Comment: @FarshiDNaqizadeh I don't think you can guarantee the same output.  Unless both java and python use exactly the same model, then you will experience differences.  The models are updated from time to time and I have seen differences between java and python.  For example the part of speech tags have been updated.  Stanza have produced papers that explain their changes when models are updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately doing this isn't possible. While both CoreNLP (Java) and Stanza (formerly stanfordnlp, Python) do considerably overlapping things (part of speech, named entity recognition, parsing), their internals are completely different, dating from different decades. You cannot load Stanza models into CoreNLP, and there is at present no support for Persian in CoreNLP.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by myself?

Comment: You could train Persian models for Stanford CoreNLP, and make any code changes needed to get things working. (CoreNLP tends to have some per-language code.) If someone did that and the data was available (for future retraining), we'd be happy to merge it as a PR on github.